# UINavigationController not displaying

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller

I am new to IOS dev so I'm sure the answer is simple but my ignorance makes it hard to find the answers online. I'm trying to use a UINavigationController to switch between views. Thus far I have been succesfully displaying the first view with the following code.

```
FLInitialMapViewController *control = [[FLInitialMapViewController alloc] init];    
self.window.rootViewController = control;
```

I then wrote the code to add the navigation controller but when I run it I see mostly a black screen with a gray bar at the top of it. Here's the code

```
FLInitialMapViewController *control = [[FLInitialMapViewController alloc] init];
_navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:control];
self.window.rootViewController = _navController;
```

Here is the complete code for AppDelegate.m in 'didFinishLaunchingWithOptions':

```
self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];

FLInitialMapViewController *control = [[FLInitialMapViewController alloc] init];

self.navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController: control];
[self.navController setNavigationBarHidden:YES];

self.window.rootViewController = self.navController;

[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
return YES;
```

Interestingly, the gray bar near the top is slightly translucent and I can see some of my UI elements underneath it.

EDIT: I removed the top bar and now I see the following!

[image]

This is what should be seen.

[image]

Comment: Are you setting the `UINavigationController` in the `AppDelegate.m`? Assuming that you started with an `Empty Application`. Please share a screenshot.

Comment: This code is in AppDelegate.m. Isn't the code above setting the navcontroller?

Answer (score 0):

I have added navigation bar setup for your convenience. Try this in your `AppDelegate.m` under `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` method -

```
FLInitialMapViewController * control = [FLInitialMapViewController new];

UINavigationController *myNav = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController: control];
self.window.rootViewController = myNav;

// Setup navigation bar programmatically  
UINavigationBar *navigationBar = myNav.navigationBar;
navigationBar.barTintColor = [UIColor orangeColor];
navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlackOpaque;

// Boiler plate code from AppDelegate 
self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

Comment: No changes. Is it possible that my controller is not adding elements to the view correctly? Because it appears that my elements are being displayed but underneath the navigation controller.

Comment: Do you want the code for the controller? Because that codes pretty long and I don't know what else would be relevant.

Comment: Not from the controller. But, from your `AppDelegate.h` and `AppDelegate.m`. Just update the question with complete code. I hope you started with an 'Empty Application' (which we had in Xcode 5.1).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63568/discussion-between-raurora-and-nate).